# MEAN Stack How to save data from radio type AngularJS form into MongoDB

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

I'm going nuts!

I have a multistep form to get information based on user choice. All of the choices are type = radio except name because it takes text as type. For that form, I've used AngularJS (I know it is EOL) with ui-router.

**formCtrl.js**

```
.controller('formController', function($scope, $http) {
    
    // we will store all of our form data in this object
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.regForm = function(formData){
        $http.post('/api/forms', JSON.stringify($scope.formData))
        .success(function(data,status){
            console.log("success");
        });
    }  
});
```

After submitting the form I get

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/api/forms
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
```

And **payload**

```
{
  "area": "sell clothes",
  "type": "basic",
  "name": "asdas",
  "tema": "boho"
}
```

But because of backend in express, **Preview** looks like this, came from **api.js**

```
success: false, message: "Ensure completing all the fields!"}
message
: 
"Ensure completing all the fields!"
success
: 
false
```

**api.js**

```
var Form = require("../models/form");

module.exports = function (router) {
  // http://localhost:8080/api/forms

  router.post("/forms", function (req, res) {
    // res.send('Testing users route');

    var form = new Form();
    form.area = req.body.area;
    form.responsive = req.body.responsive;
    form.name = req.body.name;
    form.tema = req.body.tema;


    if (
      req.body.area == null ||
      req.body.responsive == null ||
      req.body.name == null ||
      req.body.area == "" ||
      req.body.tema == null
    ) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: "Ensure completing all the fields!",
      });
    } else {
      form.save(function (err) {
        //check if there is an error
        if (err) {
          res.json({ success: false, message: "Complete all the fields!" });
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.json({ success: true, message: "Form created!" });
        }
      });
    }
  });

  return router;
};
```

So the problem is, I can get 200 OK message but doesn't pass through express in here

```
 var form = new Form();
        form.area = req.body.area;
        form.responsive = req.body.responsive;
        form.name = req.body.name;
        form.tema = req.body.tema;
```

But if I use **Postman** and make a post request in body JSON I can save it to MongoDB.
So somehow, AngularJS and Express cannot communicate.

What it is the right way for me to get `formData` from user choice that are radio options and send it to a database in the MongoDB???

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

for setup angular and backend with submit form data to the mongodb please refer `https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/mongodb-odata-angularjs.rst`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `req.body.responsive` it should be `req.body.type` since the data is `type` instead of `responsive`!

For anyone trying to use angularjs form and save it to mongodb can use it. Both frontend and backend part is working!